# jquery - How do I add an alert message to this jquery code base?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

### **The Question**

To help avoid end-user confusion, I want to add an alert message that pops up if/when the user clicks any other key ["alert('Only Numerical data allowed')"].  So if they press the 'k' the above message will pop up.  Can anyone see how to set this code within this code base

- **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EN8pT/4/

---

### **The Code**

**jquery**:

```
$('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    var w = e.which;
    return (w != 8 && w != 0 && (w < 48 || w > 57) && w != 46) ? false : true;
});
```

​

**html**

```
<div class="containercontent">

         <div class="label">Enter a number:</div>
        <input type="text" name="txtNumber1" id="txtNumber1" value=""  class="numberinput" />

         <div class="label">Enter a number:</div>
        <input type="text" name="txtNumber2" id="txtNumber2" value="" class="numberinput" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can I suggest assigning `e.which` to a variable, just to avoid re-evaluating it five times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello again :) I can help you out with this as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var allow = (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46) ? false : true;
        if (!allow) {
            alert('Only Numerical data allowed');
        }
        return allow;
    });
});?
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EN8pT/3/

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Simple :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input.numberinput').bind('keypress', function (e) {

    if((e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46) )
    {
       alert('Only Numbers');
        return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
});
});
```

Link  : http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/EN8pT/